# Pointer to a Pointer to a Structure and malloc memory for array

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm creating a pointer to a pointer to a structure to create a dynamic array with malloc in C, but I get a segmentation fault calling the struct array. Here is a quick rundown of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int test1;
    int test2;
    }testStruct;

int main() {
    testStruct **neato;

    neato = (testStruct **) malloc( sizeof(testStruct *) * 5);
    // Array of 5 for convience

    // any neato[x]->testy call results in segmentation fault.
    scanf("%d", &neato[0]->test1);    // Segmentation fault

    return 0;
    }
```

I tried other calls like (*neato)[0].test1 and all result in segmentation fault. This is obviously not the proper way to do this or my GNU compiler is seriously outdated.

Comment: Do not cast the return value of `malloc`. See: http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've allocated enough memory for 5 pointers.  You have not however initialized the pointers, so they are garbage.  Allocate the pointers and then proceed to initialize each pointer.

```
int elems = 5;

neato = malloc(sizeof(testStruct *) * elems);
for( i = 0; i < elems; ++i ) {
    neato[i] = malloc(sizeof(testStruct));
}
```

On a side note, I don't see a need for an array of pointers here.  Why not simply allocate enough space for 5 `testStruct`s (i.e., `neato` becomes a `testStruct*`) and pass the address of that pointer to the function that initializes it?

Comment: D'oh! Went straight over my head. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you aren't `mallocing` space for all the structures themselves you have to add

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    neato[i] = malloc(sizeof(testStruct));
}
```

After you malloc neato. Also you should check your return value from malloc for `NULL` to make sure malloc passed.

Comment: No need to cast the result of `malloc` in C.

Comment: @EdS. True but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: It can actually. It's just totally unnecessary, serving only to add verbosity to your code, and it can actually be bad in a more meaningful way.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 0):

You allocated array of pointers, but did not assign valid address to these pointers.

If you only want to create dynamic array, use just pointer to the struct:

```
testStruct *neato;
neato = malloc( sizeof(testStruct) * 5);
scanf("%d", &neato[0].test1);
```